# UISearchBarBackground Class

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I am using the following piece of code to hide the background on a UISearchBar:
[[searchView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:YES];
Pretty simple, but I worry about hard coding a position in a subview list.
So I went looking for the UISearchBarBackground.h file and cannot find it.
Does any know where the definition is hiding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply use in
[subView isKindOfClass:[UISearchBarBackground class]] the following works just fine:

@interface UISearchBarBackground : NSObject {
}
@end

A more complete definition is available at github.

Comment: http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UISearchBarBackground.h

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
for (UIView* subview in searchControl.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UISearchBarBackground"]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an answer to the asked question

Answer (score 0):

For ios4 it didnt work, so I try this and it works

> [[self.mySearchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSClassFromString() method this instead to avoid having to create a new class just for testing equallity

```
for (UIView *v in [self.searchbar subviews]) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        // whatever you want to do with the subview goes here...
    }
}
```